# Make highchart columns extend to edge

Tags: highcharts

I have not been able tow work out how to extend my column highchart right to the very edge.

In the image below, the blue area is the highcharts div, and the red area is the "wasted space" I want to elimiate.

What is the best way to do this?

[image]

EDIT: here is my (simplified) config in coffee script and a gif to better explain the problem

```
     graphEl.highcharts
                    chart:
                        animation:false
                        margin: [0,0,0,0]
                        spacing: [0,0,0,0]
                        zoomType: false
                    credits:false
                    navigation:
                        buttonOptions:
                            enabled: false
                    pane:
                        size: "100%"
                    plotOptions:
                        spline:
                            marker:
                                radius: 0
                        line:
                            border:1
                            marker:
                                radius: 0
                        column:
                            grouping:false
                            pointPadding: 0
                            pointPlacement: "on"
                            groupPadding: 0
                            padding:0
                            borderWidth: 0
                            borderColor: "transparent"

                    title:
                        text: ""

                    subtitle:
                        text: ""

                    xAxis:
                        startOnTick: true
                        endOnTick: true
                        lineColor: "#F3F3F3"
                        tickColor: "#F3F3F3"
                        labels:
                            enabled:false
                            step:1
                    yAxis: [ # Primary yAxis
                        type: 'column'
                        min:0
                        gridLineWidth: 0
                        minorGridLineWidth: 0
                        lineColor: "#3782C1"
                        labels:
                            format: ""
                            style:
                                display: "none"
                        title:
                            text: ""
                            style:
                                display: "none"
                    ]
                    dataLabel:
                        useHTML:true
                    legend:
                        padding: 0
                        floating: true
                        style:
                            display: "none"
                    series: seriesList
```

[image]

Comment: You can set minPadding/maxPadding on xAxis as 0, but all depends if you use categores or number xAxis. Recreate simple demo, if our answers will not solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve that my managing group padding and point padding.

by setting both of them to 0 you can get rid of that extra spacing but that will result in equal reduction of space between the interior columns as well. so advice you to go with, tickmarkPlacement option.

```
xAxis : {
    tickmarkPlacement : 'on'
}
```

Examples

tickmarkPlacement : http://jsfiddle.net/oj3odzkf/

managing groupPadding as well: http://jsfiddle.net/oj3odzkf/1/

Hope this will help you